# In how many ways can we choose 5 balls from the box so that we have at least one blue ball?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A box has ten blue balls numbered from 1 to 10 and ten green balls numbered from 1 to 10.

In how many ways can we choose 5 balls from the box so that we have at least one blue ball?

I'm trying to do it by subtracting total by no blue balls but I don't think I'm getting the right answer

Has exactly one blue ball--$5*10*10*9*8*7$ (5 because the first step is to chose where the blue ball goes)

is that how you're suppose to do it then do 2 blue balls etc?

Comment: Do you distinguish between different balls of the same color?

Comment: @M.B. Given that they are numbered, looks like it.

Comment: Oops, sorry. :)

Answer (score 1):

The order in which the balls are drawn is irrelevant. Let the green balls have numbers from $1$ to $10$ and the blue balls have numbers from $11$ to $20$.

There are ${20\choose 5}=15\,504$ subsets of five balls from all twenty balls.

There are  are ${10\choose 5}=252$ subsets of five balls from these twenty balls, when only the numbers from $1$ to $10$ may occur.

It follows that $15\,504-252={\bf 15\,252}$ subsets of five contain at least one ball with number $>10$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you want to subtract the total by no blue balls, that's a good way to do it.

The total is ${n}\choose{k}$. Now let's think about how many ways we can choose $10$ green balls. Well, on the first pick there are $10$ ways to pick a green ball, since there are $10$ green balls. After that there are $9$ ways to pick the next green ball. Hence we have $10*9*...$

Can you solve it from here?

Comment: Lets say there are 3 green balls numbered 1,2,3. Is it 6 ways of drawing 3 balls from this collection?

Comment: 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321. 6 ways. In other words, 3*2*1

Comment: Yeah, but I would assume those are counted as equal.

Comment: I see. Well, I guess I'm making a different assumption. I mean, suppose you have 9 red balls and 1 black ball. You have one pick. I would say you have 9 ways of choosing a red ball and only 1 way to pick a black one

Comment: Sure, and I would agree! But that is not what we are disagreeing on.

Comment: In that case, I guess I'm not following you. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I would agree that picking ball 1 is different from picking ball 9. I would however not agree that if we were to draw two balls then 1,2 and 2,1 are to be viewed as different.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11408/discussion-between-kbball-and-m-b)

Answer (score 0):

The key instrument you have to use here is the *binomial coefficient* $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, which indicates the number of possible ways to choose $k$ elements from a set of $n$ objects.

The number of ways to draw exactly $1$ blue ball is found as follows: You choose $1$ blue ball among $10$, and then $4$ green balls among $10$, so you get
$$\binom{10}{1}\binom{10}{4} = \frac{(10!)^2}{9!4!5!} = 12600$$
possible ways. Obviously if you want also to take into account the order of drawing, you have to multiply by $5! = 120$.

Now you can use this method to find the number of ways you can draw at least one blue ball.

Comment: That's the answer for *exactly* one blue ball.  The OP asked for *at least one*.

Comment: @BarryCipra Sure, but I wanted to leave to the OP the computation for $2$, $3$ etc. blue balls as an exercise, in order to undertand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is best, regardless of whether you think your answer is right.

There are $\binom{20}{5} = \frac{20!}{5!15!} = \frac{20*19*18*17*16}{5!}=19*3*17*16$ total ways to choose 5 balls. 
To choose only green balls, there are $\binom{10}{5} = \frac{10!}{5!5!}=\frac{10*9*8*7*6}{5!}=9*8*7$ total ways. Hence there must be $19*3*17*16 - 9*8*7 = 15000$ ways to choose at least one blue ball.